# Is there a way to clone a local git repository together with its staged and non-staged changes?

Tags: git, git-clone

I want to write a script that clones a local git repo multiple times, but also copies over all non-committed changes over to the cloned repos. Is this possible?

Had a look at [git-clone](http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html), but didn't see such an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have direct access to the repo you're cloning? If so, you can just commit all the changes in the source repo (`git add -A`, `git commit -m "non-commited changes"`). Then clone the repo and run `git reset HEAD^` in those other repos. Once you are done with cloning, also run `git reset HEAD^` in your source repo.

That should do exactly what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Staged and non-staged changes are not a part of the repository so no, you cannot do that. If you want that you can just copy the directory with the repo and the working copy.

Comment: Actually, in a weird sense, staged changes _are_ in the repository (they're loose objects whose reference is only in the index, not in any commit in the commit-tree), but in practice your answer (just copy the thing directly) is the easiest way to go. :-)